# error on implicit declaration, but function is declared in source file

Tags: c, implicit-declaration

I am trying to build a wireless driver which is eventually failing on an implicit declaration error:

```
wl_iw.c: In function 'wl_iw_set_priv':
wl_iw.c:7649:4: error: implicit declaration of function 'wl_iw_set_cscan' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

Here is where it tries to call the function:

```
#if defined(CSCAN)

    else if (strnicmp(extra, CSCAN_COMMAND, strlen(CSCAN_COMMAND)) == 0)
        ret = wl_iw_set_cscan(dev, info, (union iwreq_data *)dwrq, extra);
#endif
```

So, it seems like this will only be called if CSCAN is defined.  Well, in the source file, wl_iw_set_cscan is also declared if CSCAN is declared (*I believe*).  [Here is where it is defined (github)](https://github.com/gnychis/android-wmon-core/blob/master/compat-wireless-3.6-rc7-1/drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/wl_iw.c#L6162), and... [if you scroll up a little bit, it only seems to be dependent on CSCAN being defined](https://github.com/gnychis/android-wmon-core/blob/master/compat-wireless-3.6-rc7-1/drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/wl_iw.c#L5948).

CSCAN is definitely defined, which is shown if I do a verbose build:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc *snip* -DCSCAN *snip* -c -o /home/owner/android-wmon/core/compat-wireless-3.6-rc7-1/drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/wl_iw.o /home/owner/android-wmon/core/compat-wireless-3.6-rc7-1/drivers/net/wireless/bcmdhd/wl_iw.c
```

I can even be doubly sure by putting a "#define CSCAN" at the top of wl_iw.c and it will complain that it is defined twice.  So I'm positive that CSCAN is defined.

If this is the case, why am I getting an implicit definition warning turned error?  wl_iw_set_cscan should be defined since CSCAN is defined.

Comment: thanks, this was the problem.  if you pose it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Running your source file through `gcc -E` can help find this kind of problem; it shows the preprocessor output.

Comment: That's a great comment, Keith.  I never knew that flag existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At line 5781, there is another `#define` that is masking `wl_iw_set_cscan`.